# how to add string in previous line to the end of next line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, text

I want to add string startswith "AA" to the end of next line like this
(that have many lines in text)

input:

```
AA

1 A B C 

2 D E F 

AA

3 G H I
```

output:

```
1 A B C AA

2 D E F 

3 G H I AA
```

Comment: You want to concatenate two strings?

Comment: concatenate string in line before to the end of next line

Answer (score 0):

you need to keep two lists, a temporary one to keep all your string that start with "AA" and other for the output and fill them accordingly

```
>>> text="""AA

1 A B C

2 D E F

AA

3 G H I"""

>>> output=[]
>>> temp=[]
>>> for line in text.splitlines():
        line = line.strip() #remove trailing while spaces
        if not line:
            continue #ignore empty lines
        if line.startswith("AA"):
            temp.append(line)
        else:
            if temp: #concatenate our temp list if there anything there
                line += " " + " ".join(temp)
                temp.clear() 
            output.append(line)
    
            
>>> print("\n".join(output))
1 A B C AA
2 D E F
3 G H I AA
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import sys # To use stdin(standard input) function
checker="AA" # Make var for chekcing word
raw=sys.stdin.readlines()
#paste text from clipboard and ctrl + z input
#If you takes too long time to paste text from clipboard
#Look below another code which to make lines list.
lines=list(map(str.strip,raw))
result=[]
for i in range(0,len(lines)-1):
    if lines[i] == checker:
        result.append(lines[i+1]+lines[i])
    else:
        pass
result_str='\n'.join(result)
print(result_str)
```

I hope it wiil work for you.

If your raw text's lines bigger than 1,000 than I reconnand you use open function. Here is some example.
your raw text file name is raw.txt and same folder with python file.

```py
lines='' # Make empty str var
with open('raw.txt', 'r') as f: 
    lines=f.readlines(): # read all lines with escape code (\n)
    Map=map(str.strip, lines) # remove escape code by map, strip function.
    lises=list(Map) #to using slicing Map should transformed list.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank bot. 
I edit my answer as I can as possible. Again I hope it work for #Park